# Is it possible to make FaceTime not open the camera on startup?

Tags: macos, facetime

I rarely use FaceTime on the MBP, but it's linked to my AppleID so that I can keep track of missed calls without reaching for the phone. However, I don't like having it start the camera and showing me my face as soon as it starts, because:

1. It's distracting from the actual information I am looking at: the list of calls;
2. As handsome as I am, I am not that big a narcissist to keep staring at my own face;
3. I prefer audio calls, so I rarely have occasion to keep the camera active anyway.

How can I make FaceTime just show the list of recent calls without showing the camera feed?

I'm on macOS High Sierra 10.13.4 (17E199).

Comment: Black sticky tape? ;)

Comment: I have considered getting one of those sliding locks. :/ But I'd rather not ruin the good looks of the mbp :P